# How to simulate link server down?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

In SQL Server, I have created a link server to MySql database.
When the link server is queried from SQL Server and if the MySql server is down, we want to receive an alert. I have no control over the MySql database(link server points to) and without actually stopping the MySql server, how to simuate the database server down(MySql).

I tried to simulate the server down by providing invalid name for link server("IncorrectLinkServerName") but do not think this is a true test for server down. Is this correct way to validate server down? If there is a better way to test this, please share.

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC sp_testlinkedserver [IncorrectLinkServerName];';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'Database down alert' AS Result
END CATCH
```

Comment: Maybe kill the networking between the servers?

Comment: I want to use killing/blocking the network as last option as I am working in Prod. Secondly, I feel killing/blocking the traffic is different from database down(i may be wrong)

Comment: Working in production is part of the problem here. Make a test environment. Spinning up a couple of containers or VMs can't be a huge hassle, or at least a smaller hassle than dealing with accidentally messing up production beyond repair.